# How to sort by a column in union query in SqlAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have the following queries,

```
query1 = session.query(User.name, Info.zipCode.label('zip'))
                .join(Info, User.user_id=Info.user_id)
```

---

```
query2 = session.query(User.name, Addr.postCode.label('zip'))
                 .join(Addr, User.user_id=Addr.employee_id)
```

---

```
query = query1.union(query2)
```

How do I order by the `"zip"` column?

Answer (score 1):

You have `query`, which is a [Query](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/query.html#the-query-object) object. A query has an [`order_by()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.order_by) function, which can [take a literal string](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/tutorial.html#using-literal-sql) if desired. So, the easiest way to do this would be...

```
query = query1.union(query2).order_by('zip')
```

Comment: @Will - see a comment left in docs: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.union - `Note that many database backends do not allow ORDER BY to be rendered on a query called within UNION,`