# How to use order_by with UNION in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy, sql-order-by, union

I'm using SQLAlchemy UNION, ORDER_BY is not working, it throwing this
error

**Can't resolve label reference for ORDER BY/ GROUP BY/ DISTINCT etc. Textual SQL expression 'LastName' should be explictly declared as text('LastName')**

```
query1 = db.query(Employee.LastName).filter(Employee.Age == 30)
query2 = db.query(Employee.LastName).filter(Employee.Salary > 25000)
result = query1.union(query2).order_by('LastName').all()
```

Then I tried the below line too, but it didn't work, its throwing this error

**(pyodbc.ProgrammingError)('42S22',"[42S22][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server] invalid column name 'LastName'. [SQL Server] Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)**

```
result = query1.union(query2).order_by(text('LastName').all()
```

Comment: See the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232596/how-to-sort-by-a-column-in-union-query-in-sqlalchemy There is a comment there that links to the sqlalchemy docs which I will repeat here: `Note that many database backends do not allow ORDER BY to be rendered on a query called within UNION`. So this may be the case for you too (what DB are you using on your backend?).  Updated link to sql alchemy docs: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html?highlight=union#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.union

Comment: snakecharmerb, I edited the question and added the exact error messages it is throwing

Comment: What is the column name on the database side?  Could it be `lastname`?

Comment: Yes, The column name on database side is LastName

Answer (score 0):

Reference from：
[Selecting Entities from UNIONs and other set operations](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/queryguide.html#orm-queryguide-unions)

1. Use a UNION to join two tables as a subquery.
2. Use SELECT * FROM the subquery.
3. Sort the result after the query.

example：

```
    smtm = union(table1, table2)
    subq = smtm.subquery()
    smtm = select(subq).order_by(desc(subq.c.order_date))
    res = session.execute(smtm.limit(size).offset((page - 1) * size)).all()
```